# Converting "Ð±Ð¾Ð»Ð½Ð¾" to Cyrillic

Tags: unicode, encoding, character-encoding, character, cyrillic

I have problem in my database where some of the Cyrillic text is seen like this `"Ð±Ð¾Ð»Ð½Ð¾ Ð±Ð°Ñ Ð°Ð¼ÑŒÐ´Ñ€ÑƒÑƒÐ»Ð¶ Ñ‡ Ð"`.   Is there a way to convert this to back to human readable format.

I need to read actual context of this.

Comment: What encoding was used to get that?  Post the raw byte data not the mis-decoded mojibake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Best I could do from your data...it looks Cyrillic but Google Translate didn't make anything of it. It seems it was decoded under the default US Windows codec but was really UTF-8, but the data is not quite right.  I'm using Python to attempt to fix it:

```
>>> s.encode('cp1252').decode('utf8',errors='replace')
'болно ба� амьдруулж ч �'
```

Comment: In Windows-1252 the following bytes don’t correspond to a character: h81, h8D, h8F, h90 and h9D. With a leading hD1 byte in UTF-8 (`Ñ`), they correspond to small Cyrillic letters с, э, я, ѐ and ѝ, respectively. With a leading hD0 (`Ð`), that would be uppercase Ё, Ѝ, Џ, А and Н instead. These are the Cyrillic letters that will show as replacement char `�`, because the OP didn’t provide the exact byte string and so the illegal byte was simply dropped. If this is Russian, the corrupted word was likely бас ‘and, also’ or perhaps бая ‘the rich’.